# Passing Data from multiple activities to one activity

Tags: java, android-studio

I have created three different activities with three different ListViews similar to this and created another activity with a Button.

The purpose is to select any item from any ListView and it will change the Button text to the selected item I choose.

Here is the code I use to create the ListViews:

```java
public class C_Camera extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView_C_Camera;

    String[] listview_c_camera = new String[]{
            "a" , "b", "c", "d" , "e" , "f","g", "h","i","j"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c__camera);

        listView_C_Camera = findViewById(R.id.listview_c_camera);

        ArrayAdapter<String> CanonCamera = new ArrayAdapter<>(this , R.layout.listview_row,listview_c_camera);
        listView_C_Camera.setAdapter(CanonCamera);

        listView_C_Camera.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String C_Camera_Temp = listview_c_camera[position];

                Intent intent = new Intent(C_Camera.this, BuildCamera.class);
                intent.putExtra("C_Camera",C_Camera_Temp);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have another activity with a Button that will get the values of the three different ListViews.

```java
public class BuildCamera extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button camerabuild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_build_camera);

        camerabuild = findViewById(R.id.camerabuild);

        String C_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("C_Camera");
        String N_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("N_Camera");
        String S_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("S_Camera");
        camerabuild.setText(C_Camera_Holder);
        camerabuild.setText(N_Camera_Holder);
        camerabuild.setText(S_Camera_Holder);
    ...
```

Here I'm facing a problem.

If I use `String C_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("C_Camera")` and comment the others it will work and change the text,

```java
String C_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("C_Camera");
//   String N_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("N_Camera");
//  String S_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("S_Camera");
camerabuild.setText(C_Camera_Holder);
//   camerabuild.setText(N_Camera_Holder);
//   camerabuild.setText(S_Camera_Holder);
```

but if I uncomment the second one (`String N_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("N_Camera")`) the first one will stop changing the text and the second will do and so on.

```java
String C_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("C_Camera");
String N_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("N_Camera");
//   String S_Camera_Holder = getIntent().getStringExtra("S_Camera");
camerabuild.setText(C_Camera_Holder);
camerabuild.setText(N_Camera_Holder);
//   camerabuild.setText(S_Camera_Holder);
```

Comment: camerabuild.setText(); will carry only 1 text which the the last line of code you call the setText() function.

Answer (score 1):

the button will always carry the last setText() function that you call.

```
    camerabuild.setText(C_Camera_Holder);
    camerabuild.setText(N_Camera_Holder);
    camerabuild.setText(S_Camera_Holder); <<----------which is, this one.
```

to make it dynamic on your activity intents  you can use `if` statement.

like this

```
    if(C_Camera_Holder != null){
        camerabuild.setText(C_Camera_Holder);
    }else if(N_Camera_Holder != null){
        camerabuild.setText(N_Camera_Holder);
    }else if(S_Camera_Holder != null){
        camerabuild.setText(S_Camera_Holder);
    }
```

Comment: When I write the code u suggested when I click on the button trying to go to the next activity the application stops working.

Comment: probably null exception change this `!C_Camera_Holder.isEmpty()` to `C_Camera_Holder != null` the same with the rest. also application crash produces error trace on logcat you can learn more about the error there.